# ImportError: cannot import name actions

Tags: python, django

Trying to run django project, installed all stuff from requirements.txt but still getting error

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, actions
ImportError: cannot import name actions
```

Can't find anything useful about it. Does anybody know how to fix it?

UPDATE:

I've found that there is no settings.py file but settings folder instead of it and it contains common.py and production.py and no settings.py. May be that's the problem?

Comment: What project are you using? I think the problem isn't the settings module (it doesn't have to be `settings.py`)

Comment: It is commercial project that I need to run localy.

Comment: Looks like a third-party application problem: https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-longer-username/issues/15

Comment: I solved this issue and added solution in response below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to run import manually in python shell like this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "chipped.settings.common")
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, actions
```

And it told me that there is no `postgresql_psycopg2` module. I changed database engine to `django.db.backends.sqlite3` and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

i got this error when i upgraded my os x to mavericks

as quux mentioned, you can get real error from python shell and indeed it was _psycopg.so referencing some library that's not available.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, actions

Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/nreeves/venvs/gd_api_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Reason: image not found
```

so i need to have library link to where _psycopg.so look for.
first I need to locate the lib itself

i installed with brew so my lib is here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib
```

then I created symlink to /usr/lib (or /usr/local/lib)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib /usr/lib
```

and all fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, turns out I had my database password wrong in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me on the one of my projects. I used last version of psycopg2.
I installed to psycopg2==2.5.3 (my other projects use it version) and now it works.

Answer (score -3):

What is `actions`? You get this error because it isn't present in [the admin module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/actions.py).