# How to integrate celery with Django, when settings needs to be injected in?

Tags: python, django, celery

I am working on a new project where every developer has his own settings file.

In order to run Django I have to load it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings="databank_web.settings.dqs.dev_houman"
```

I have now to integrate Celery 3.1 into the project and this approach is causing me a lot of headache.

I have followed all the steps to integrate the Celery into Django as described [here.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django)

I can run Django as usual, but now I have to run celery with my custom Django environment as described in this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864876/celery-3-1-9-django-integration-specifying-settings-file-without-using-djceler)

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='databank_web.settings.dqs.dev_houman' celery -A databank_web worker -l info
```

This seems to get a step further, but I get this error message:

```
File "/Users/houman/git/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, actions
ImportError: cannot import name actions
```

I did some research and followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24188232/92153) in order to narrow it down:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "databank_web.settings.dqs.dev_houman")
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, actions
```

This was meant to clarify which error is throwing, however it seems to work just fine. So I am clueless why this is failing within Django environment.

So why am I getting those `ImportError: cannot import name actions` errors?

Much appreciated

Comment: Since every developer has her own settings file it is likely that you have something wrong in it. Try executing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24188232/356729) in a Python shell to track down the real error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like a circular dependency.

If you followed the guide, you should have created a new file called `celery.py`.

In `celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Comment out `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')` because this is trying to overwrite whatever you pass outside the scope.

Then, set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable outside the file.